# How to filter contents in linked list using select statement?

Tags: database, orientdb, nosql

A class has a property which holds link of rid's.ie testcaseLink:[#20:0,#20:1].I have a problem in selecting only certain rids from the testcaseLink using select statement.

Looking for something like **select testcaseLink.get(#20:0)** from tableName.Is there is any method to filter the contents of collections in orientdb

Comment: On which criteria do you want to filter your data? If you want the first element you can can use `select testcaseLink[0]`, if you want to filter them based on linked document properties, you can use an expression between square brackets `select testcaseLink[ prop = 'foo']`. Filtering based on RID is the same as a simple property filtering, eg. `select testcaseLink[ @rid = #20:0]`

Comment: Filter based on Rid .By **select testcaseLink[ @rid = #20:0] ** we can get only rid record but I want to filter it based on mutiple rid like **select testcaseLink[ rid = #20:0,rid = #20:1] **

Comment: Thanks Luigi ,select testcaseLink[ @rid = #20:0] triggered me to find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select testCaseLink[@rid=#20:6 OR @rid=#20:8] from tableName where ColumnName='Value' Solved the problem